# Is this a constraint optimisation problem? If so, which OR-tools template is most appropriate?

Tags: python, optimization, or-tools

I'm a little bit *conceptually lost* with the right approach to the problem I'm solving. I think Google's [OR tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization/introduction/get_started) can potentially be a direction I can go, but unsure how to get started.

This is a **shipping cost optimisation** problem - I have 3 packages, and 5 different shipping providers. Each package has a weight and longest dimension, and each provider has restrictions on these dimensions, and potential surcharges based on the dimensions of the package.

For example, let's say the packages are represented with the following dicts:

```
package_one = {"weight":10, "longest_dim": 120}
package_two = {"weight":12, "longest_dim": 60}
```

And say the shipping providers have the following constraints:

```
provider_one = {"max_weight": 10, "longest_dim": 150, "cost_per_item": 3.99}
provider_two = {"max_weight": 25, "longest_dim": 200, "cost_per_item": 10.99}
provider_three = {"max_weight": 15, "longest_dim": 100, "cost_per_item": 4.99}
```

What I'm looking to do is **find the cheapest way of delivering all the packages** - so in this case, even though `provider_two` can ship the packages (since their combined weight is 22 and combined height is 180, meeting the constraint requirements), the cost would be $21.98, whereas if `package_one` was sent by `provider_one` while `package_two` was sent by `provider_two` it would cost $8.98.

In summary, my questions are something like:

1. Can you solve this problem using OR tools - if so, what model would be most appropriate (bin-packing? scheduling?) and what are some things to consider
2. Would this be a two-pronged approach - do I first need to look at *feasibility* (e.g. what group of packages is possible to send with a shipping provider within its constraints) *and then* consider cost optimisation?

Thanks in advance for your help - this has been melting my brain all day.

Answer (score 0):

Start by writing the equations.

You can create one Boolean variable per item and per provider.
Then add constraints for the feasibility of the problem (only shipped once, must be shipped, must fit...)

Then add the objective part.

About solving, this is a simple linear problem with Boolean equations.
CP-SAT or the linear solver wrapper are good fit.

Comment: Hi Laurent, helpful to know that this is a reasonable problem to tackle with CP-SAT. I've been looking through the examples on the OR-Tools Google page and not sure on a couple of things:
(i) how would I represent a provider sending 2+ packages in the variables
(ii) I have an 'additional item charge' for 2+ packages being sent by a provider. Would this be a part of the variable declaration or a constraint?
(iii) for the optimisation, I'm trying to minimise the cost of sending all packages, so would this optimisation be done in situations with multi-provider, multi-package deliveries?

Comment: (i) Let x[p,s] be a boolean variable meaning that package p is shipped by shipper s. Then sum(x[i,s] for i = 1 to number of packages) is the number shipped by shipper s. Make a new variable for the sum and create a constraint to enforce that its value is equal to the sum. (ii) You'll need a constraint that enforces the extra charge if the sum is > 1. See https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/channeling for some hints. iii) If you use the model to optimize it optimizes over whatever is defined in the model.